# NODE env variables script runs in bash but not in zsh

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, zsh

I have a file (`env/api.env`) with my Node environment variables and I am running this script in bash to publish the variables:

```
export $(cat env/api.env | grep -v ^#)
```

If I try to run it in zsh instead of bash it will not work. Variables will just be not published and stay as undefined.

How can I do a script that runs in both bash / zsh ?

Comment: How about a sample of the contents of the file?

Comment: Is just a set of variables like:

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3307
DB_TEST_HOST=localhost
DB_TEST_PORT=3308

Comment: It's relevant. Please [add it to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45828944/edit).

Comment: @armova: I can't reproduce it in Zsh 5.3. I suggest that you re-run your code with `-x`.

Comment: @armova: BTW, make it simpler: `export $(grep -v ^# env/api.env)`

Comment: Try quoting the RE in the grep:  `export $(grep -v '^#' env/api.env)`

Comment: Thanks @user1934428 I updated zsh but keep having the same problem, then running your simplified version works fine in both

Comment: @cdarke : I don't think quoting is necessary here. The caret is not a special character, and the hash can't be taken as a comment because it is not the start of the word. IMO, even the original code posted here should have worked (it's just unnecessarily complicated), but without seeing a trace (as I suggested), we don't know what's going on.

Comment: @user1934428:  I agree.  The suggestion to quote was a knee-jerk comment from me without trying it.  In my defence its a good idea to always quote REs and I wasn't sure how zsh behaved.  I have since tried it (on bash and zsh) and you are right, it works with and without the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently have Zsh's `extendedglob` (AKA `EXTENDED_GLOB` in
`ZSHEXPN(1)`) option set, which is treating the unescaped `^` as a
*shell* glob negator -- before it gets to `grep`.  It's a nice Zsh
option and worth enabling IMO, but you have to quote a bit more often.

So your approach should work if you write it as:

```
% export $(grep -v '^#' env/api.env)
```

However, you're safer off just letting `api.env` be a simple shell
(Zsh and Bash compatible) file so you don't have to clumsily parse out
the comments and such.  Then it's just:

```
% source env/api.env
```

`source` is preferred to `.` in this case since you're working from
the current directory.

---

The spirit of what you're accomplishing is handled well by tools like
[direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) and
[dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv).

Comment: Could you go into more detail on `source`-vs-`.`? In bash, the docs have it as an alias with the exact same implementation, but in POSIX sh, only `.` is specified (making it the more portable option). Does zsh do something different?

Comment: Yes, `source` and `.` are identical in Bash, but Zsh distinguishes them slightly. In ZSHBUILTINS(1) for `source` we see: "Same as `.', except that the current directory is always searched and is always searched first, before directories in $path."